# Kohana - controller specific .htaccess

Tags: forms, .htaccess, file-upload, kohana, php

I'm trying to set some htaccess rules for a specific Kohana controller. Basically its to do with form uploads. The majority of the site doesn't want to allow for large uploads so the php.ini will remain with the recommended settings.

However in one place a large file upload is required. I have the following options to add in my root .htaccess:

```
php_value max_input_time 60000
php_value post_max_size "1GB"
php_value upload_max_filesize "1GB"
php_value memory_limit "128MB"
```

But I don't know what to do to make it apply just for one controller (i.e. http://www.mysite.com/massiveupload).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Better try `Location` or `LocationMatch` instead of `Files` (they works with URLs while Files with real file names). Another idea is to actually have such folder name and put these rules in .htaccess file but still make sure that such URL will be treated as controller rather than ordinary folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's also another solution. Again thanks to @LazyOne for the tip. This one is much neater, but it requires updating the Apache config directly (so you cannot deploy it on a shared hosting).

All you have to do is add this to your httpd.conf or vhosts.conf (inside `<Directory>` or `<VirtualHost>` as per [Apache Docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#locationmatch)).

```
<LocationMatch /massiveupload>
    php_flag max_input_time 60000
    php_value post_max_size 1024M
    php_value upload_max_filesize 1024M
    php_value memory_limit 128M
</LocationMatch>
```

Restart your server and it should just work!

Note, that although LocationMatch parses the `/massiveupload` as a regular expression, we cannot use `^/massiveupload` (note the `^` char to match beginning of the string). This is because it will fail if you use a ModRewrite (which changes the final request url internally).

Note, you shouldn't make `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` the exact same size, because if you upload a file that just reaches the `upload_max_filesize` limit, any other post data will cause it to exceed the `post_max_size` and the form submission will fail.

Comment: Works a treat... much nicer solution.

Answer (score 0):

What @LazyOne suggested is fairly easy to accomplish actually.

Consider this folder structure (only listing the most important files/folders):

```
application/
    bootstrap.php
lib/
    kohana-3.0.8/
        modules/
        system/
public_html/              <----- this is your DOCUMENT_ROOT
    .htaccess
    index.php
```

And consider you're using default Kohana's .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

<Files .*>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
</Files>

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

1. Now create an `upload/` folder in your `public_html/`.
2. Copy both `.htaccess` and `index.php` from your DOCUMENT_ROOT to the `upload/` folder.
3. Edit your `upload/.htaccess`: (only new changed lines displayed)

   ```
   php_flag max_input_time 86400
   php_value post_max_size 1536M
   php_value upload_max_filesize 1024M

   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /upload/
   ...
   RewriteRule .* index.php/upload/$0 [PT]
   ```
4. Edit your `upload/index.php` and update all paths ($application, $modules, $system).
   You can download the whole tested package
5. Create an upload controller.

Additionally you could split index.php into two parts (cut after defining the paths) so you don't duplicate the whole file.

Setup like this worked just well for me and you can download my test application from here: http://d.pr/ioYk

Comment: Yep... got this in. However I get a HTTP 500 error when trying to load the core.php kohana file on this line: require SYSPATH.'classes/kohana/core'.EXT;

Comment: Well, the problem is not related to this setup then. Must be something internal in your application.