# Kohana 3.0.8 problem with classes/kohana/core.php when copying kohana index.php to subdir

Tags: php, .htaccess, subdirectory, kohana-3

I'm trying to do a dirty hack in order to set some php.ini variables for a specific part of my website.

The hack is so that site wide the php.ini variables regarding POST sizes are the recommended PHP defaults. However in one area I am expecting a massive POST to be sent. This is for security reasons and so that people cant post massive objects everywhere and take up the sites RAM and processors etc.

Here's what I'm trying to do then:

1. I have created a subdirectory in the public_html area called 'massiveupload' (the controller is also called this).
2. In the folder I have place a .htaccess file which is the same as the default kohana one with a few differences (firstly RewriteBase is now /massiveupload and secondly RewriteRule is now RewriteRule .* index.php/projects/$0 [PT]). My php_values are also set here.
3. Copied the index.php file and altered the system, application, and module paths so that they're correct.

Now... if I stick phpinfo() at the top of the index file I can see that the php_values are working when I visit http://www.mysite.com/massiveupload

However when phpinfo() is taken out the website breaks at this line:

require SYSPATH.'classes/kohana/core'.EXT;

Which gives me a HTTP 500 (Internal Server Error).

I have checked the path and the file exists, file_exists() can find it too. So my guess would be that it's something within the file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having tried to debug the code further with the use of XDebug it wouldn't debug any further into the line that was causing the issue.

I have instead implemented the solution a different way, setting specifc php_values in the VirtualHost part of HTTPD config... which can be found here: [Kohana - controller specific .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613143/kohana-controller-specific-htaccess)